# PHP MySQL detect if the same user is already logged in

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have a login system and now I want to add a function that warns the user if the user is already logged in. I don't want to prevent the login, I want to let the user in, but after the user logged in, a message should appear which is warns the user because someone else is currently logged in.
I tried to make it with `session_id`, but it prevented the user, and when I logged out from my account, I can't logged in back, because the `session_id` was `NULL`.

I added the session_in to my authenticate.php file, so it can check if the user is even valid or not. And if the user is valid, set the `session-id` value to the current session's id (`session_id()`). But I don't know how to continue the code. Any help?

authenticate.php:

```
//connect to database...
if (username & password is correct) {
   $session_id = session_id();
   $qry = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE accounts SET session-id='$session_id' WHERE id = '$id'");
}
```

index.php:

```
if (user is not logged in) {
   go to login page
}

if ($session_id == session_id()) {
  echo "you are already logged in with this user. Log out that user?";
}
```

logout.php:

```
//connect to database...
$resid=mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE accounts SET session-id='' where id='$_SESSION[id]'");
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Do a `SELECT` query to see if there's already a row in `accounts` for this ID, but with a different `session_id`. This assumes you also have a `logout` function that removes the `session_id` from `accounts.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for your advices! By the way, I am not storing passwords as plain text, there is a line, which is hashing it: `$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`

Comment: That's important, but at the same time, writing your own authentication system involves a *lot* more than just password hashing. There's a huge number of threats you need to protect against which is why I strongly suggest *not* writing your own and using an existing solution whenever possible. Unless this is purely an academic exercise, you should stop here. This code cannot be trusted to be deployed.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your advice, you helped a lot. It's working. Now, I must make it secure as tadam said. Thanks a lot guys :)